# Selenium with IntelliJ

Tags: selenium-webdriver, browser-automation, eclipse

I was confused with IntelliJ, but after watching videos I see that it is an IDE, just like Eclipse. It looks somewhat similar to Eclipse, but when do people set their choice on Eclipse and when on IntelliJ?

I think that it may have to do with the framework that you use. For example, Java is compatible with Eclipse, but C# is not, as far as I know. Are there any other factors when deciding on IDE?

Answer (score 2):

It is a personal preference:

You can find out more information about IntelliJ and Eclipse here:

[Why IDEA is better?](https://dzone.com/articles/why-idea-better-eclipse)

[Eclipse, NetBeans or IntelliJ: Which is the best Java IDE?](https://jaxenter.com/eclipse-netbeans-or-intellij-which-is-the-best-java-ide-107980.html)

[How is IntelliJ better](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/21987/how-is-intellij-better-than-eclipse)

[Things possible in IntelliJ but not possible in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/239732/things-possible-in-intellij-that-arent-possible-in-eclipse)

If you want to program in C#, simply get Microsoft Visual Studio Community Version.

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse and Intellij(Community Edition) are open source.

Intellij refactoring support is better.

IntelliJ IDEA is way powerful than Eclipse, It has the best autocomplete (intellisense). Its better to play with both and compare.

for C# you have to use Visual Studio.

[This question asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19805614/eclipse-or-intellij-idea-for-selenium-webdriver-java)